# Angular 2+ using jQuery's append alternative in app.component.ts method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 7 and I have a textarea on my app.component.html file.
I have given it an id to ta.
On my app.component.ts I have a method and I want to append a string into my textarea.
So I have this:

```
// app.component.html
    <textarea id="ta"></textarea>

// app.component.ts

mymethod() {
  // $('#ta').append("this text was appended");
  // But I need to do the above without jQuery
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in jQuery, while you should think in angular. Think of the textarea as a variable. When someone updates the textarea, the variable updates as well, and backwards - if the variable updates, the textarea too.

You can use `ngModel` to bind a variable to an input or a textarea. Then, append the string to the variable, and it will update the textarea.

```
// app.component.html
  <textarea id="ta" [(ngModel)]="textareaValue"></textarea>

// app.component.ts
  public textareaValue: string;
  mymethod() {
    this.textareaValue = "this text was appended";
  }
```

Don't forget to include the FormsModule in the app module ([here you can see how](https://angular.io/guide/forms#revise-appmodulets))

Comment: It works but it's not appending...it's replacing the text in the textarea

Comment: @KevinPorche why do you need to append it to the dom tree? You can use `[innerHtml]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`, but I can't think of a reason to do so.

Comment: I tried this.textareaValue += "this text was appended"; which appends but the first addition gives me undefined

Comment: @KevinPorche because textareaValue is still `undefined`, so adding a string to undefined results in error. You can initiate the variable with an empty string, like so: `public textareaValue: string = "";`